# Last to last month

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

Following code gives me last months data from 1 to 30/31

```
 _timestamp >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) and  _timestamp <= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -0)
```

for example, if today is `18/05/2021` it will give me results from 1-04-2021 to 30/04/2021

what changes can I make to get data for: `1-03-2021` to `30/03/2021` and
`1-02-2021` to `30/02/2021`

Comment: in march, last day is 31 and in Feb it is 28/29 (if leap year).. what you want to do, by passing month in digit and you want the date range of that month?

Comment: Just add `-1+` or `-2+` before `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: Your question is unclear because your sample dates are non-sensical.

Answer (score 0):

For the dates occurring in the entire month two months before the month of the current date, you may use:

```sql
WHERE
    timestamp >= DATEADD(month, -2, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    AND
    timestamp <  DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

As of the date this answer was posted, the above `WHERE` clause would break down to this:

```sql
WHERE timestamp >= '2021-03-01 00:00:00' AND timestamp < '2021-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Some examples:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '12/2/2011';  

SELECT 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date), MONTH(@date), 1) AS [Start],
    EOMONTH(@date) AS [End];

GO

SELECT 
    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) -6, 0) AS [Start 6 ago],
    DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) -5, 0)) AS [End 6 ago],
    CAST(DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS DATE) AS [Start This],
    CAST(DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS DATE) AS [End This],
    DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0) AS [Start Next],
    DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0)) AS [End Next]
```